# setSavepoint method in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setSavepoint%28java.lang.String%29):

> ```
> Savepoint setSavepoint(String name) throws SQLException
> ```
>
> Creates a savepoint with the given name in the current transaction and returns the >new Savepoint object that represents it.
>
> if `setSavepoint` is invoked outside of an active transaction, a transaction will be started at this newly created savepoint.

It's not clear to me the last part:

"if setSavepoint is invoked outside of an active transaction, a transaction will be started at this newly created savepoint"?

Outside an active transaction? what do they mean by that?

Comment: Some RDBMS' support transactions. Transactions are ways to make your queries ACID (look that up).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I am aware of what transactions are and how to use them, however what they mean with "outside an active transaction"?

Comment: Executing a query doesn't have to be inside a Transaction. You can start one by doing `START TRANSACTION` in mysql for example, but you don't have to. If you don't, your queries will each be committed right away (depending on config).

Comment: @Rollerball, for example, there's a command [START TRANSACTION] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) And if you use setSavepoint without using START TRANSACTION, MySQL will start the transaction for you

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: you can **not** run a SQL statement *outside* a transaction (non-transactional DBMS like MySQL aside). If you don't explicitely start one, the DBMS will start one implicitely.

Comment: @omickron so they mean that with active transaction, and will create a new transaction at the point set right?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If auto-commit is `true` then the transaction will only contain the one statement.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: yes, but it will still **be** a transaction (albeit a "small" one). It's not possible to run it "outside of a transaction"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the javadoc is referring to an explicit `START TRANSACTION` all-encompassing transaction.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis JDBC drivers handles starting transactions, you should **never** start them with the database specific command as that can lead to inconsistent state of the driver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel What are some ways to start a a multi-statement spanning transaction in a database agnostic way?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Transaction boundaries are all defined in the JDBC specification and API documentation. Transaction start (and commit) is handled by the driver, on MySQL the driver probably will execute the `START TRANSACTION` statement, but as a user you should not execute that statement yourself as that will ruin the driver state (does it have a transaction, which transaction, what is its current state, etc). Calling `setAutoCommit(false)` and executing statements and ending with calling `commit()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC specification details when a transaction is to be started (eg when a statement is executed and there is no active transaction) and when it should be ended (on commit, rollback , or - when autocommit is enabled - after statement completion (after execute, or retrieving the last row of a result set) or when another statement is executed.

The api documentation you quote simply means that when you call `setSavePoint()` and there is no transaction active, that the driver will start a transaction (assuming save points are supported) and that a savepoint will be created.

Comment: What's the need of setting a SavePoint in a non active transaction? what a non active transaction would be?

Comment: @Rollerball With a savepoint you can rollback to a specific point within a transaction, at first glance you may think that rolling back to the start of the transaction does not make sense, but it might make sense 1) when rolling back + starting an entire transaction is more expensive or 2) when the code creating the savepoint does not know whether it is at the start of a transaction or a long way inside a transaction (eg when you iteratively create a savepoint, perform an operation, rollback to the savepoint on failure, or continue on success etc).